# How to assign a product tag in Shopify product using liquid

Tags: tags, shopify, product, liquid

So basically, I have two tags, "Discounted" & "Non-Discounted".

If **Compare At Price** is greater than **Price**, so according to the automation, it should automatically add the "Discounted" tag and remove the "Non-Discounted" tag.

I know the basic and I know it might start from something like this but I can't figure out the rest of the coding.

```
{% if product.compare_at_price > product.price %}

I CAN'T FIGURE OUT THIS PART THAT HOW DO I ASSIGN A TAG 

{% endif %}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

tired multiple methods but none worked

Comment: Are you thinking to modify the tags that are added to backend?

Comment: or this code logic is just for frontend display purpose?

Comment: I want to modify the tags which we call in the products so that they can appear on the collection.

Comment: backend tags are not added and removed from the frontend liquid code, you can check 3rd party app for this

Comment: this is not possible in liquid, use Admin API instead